# Django exclude from queryset if object__not_in

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

Case: a user is creating a new requisition.
I need to filter the fields(clearances) he is allowed to select/see in his requisition; based on a comparison of the following:

- users department(s)
- users workplace(s)

compared against

- departments workplace(s)
- departments clearance fields
- clearance workplace(s)

my models:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    ...
    name   = CICharField(max_length=100)
    descr  = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,blank=True,
        related_name='children',
        )
#------------------------------
    class User(AbstractUser):
    ....
    place = models.ManyToManyField(Place, blank=True, related_name='users')
    organization = models.ManyToManyField(Organization, blank=True)
    ....
#------------------------------    
   
class Organization(models.Model):
    ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,blank=True,
        related_name='children',
        )
    place = models.ManyToManyField(Place, blank=True)
    ...
#------------------------------    
class Clearance(models.Model):
    ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='clearances')
    place = models.ManyToManyField('Place', blank=True, related_name='clearances')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
#------------------------------
class Requisition(models.Model):
    ...
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    place = models.ManyToManyField(Place, blank=False, related_name='requisitions')
    clearance = models.ManyToManyField(Clearance, blank=True, related_name='requisitions')
    ...
```

Example scenario:

- user is a member of only 1 department: "Tech dpt"
- user is located in "London" and "Edinburgh"
- Tech dpt is located in "London", "Edinburgh" and "Glasgow"

The clearances for "Tech dpt" is

- C1: London
- C2: Glasgow
- C3: London and Edinburgh
- C4: Edinburgh
- C5: London, Edinburgh and Glasgow

the closest query I manage is the following:

```
users_clearances = (
            Clearance.objects
            #fetch all clearances attached to users org_units
            .filter(parent__in=user.organization.all())
            #where clearance place is also in users places
            .filter(place__in=user.place.all())
            #the following lines does not not work
            #.exclude(place__not_in=user.place.all())
            #.filter(~Q(sted__in=user.place.all()))
            #.exclude(~Q(sted__in=user.place.all()))
            )
```

since user is only member of "London" and "Edinburgh", the query **should** return
C1, C3 and C4.

However, it also returns C5.

Since C5 is connected to "London", "Edinburgh" and "Glasgow"; it matches users "London" and "Edinburgh".. but my wish is for it to **not** be joined, as user has no affiliation in "Glasgow"

**edit**:
my closest solution is to filter the queryset afterwards.
This is suboptimal, but this at least gives me the desired result.

```
for clearance in user_clearances:
    for place in clearance.place.all():
        if place not in user.place.all():
            user_clearances = user_clearances.exclude(id=clearance.id)
```

Comment: Can you try with `Clearance.objects.filter(parent__in=user.organization.all(), place__in=user.place.all())`

Comment: That is the same query I tried above, - which unfortunately also returns clearances that contain places the user does not belong to (C5)..  think I need a ".exclude(something)" in the query.. ?

Comment: Doing two `.filter()`s can have different results when filtering on multi-valued relationships. So I was suggesting to move those two filters to just one. So instead of `.filter(a).filter(b)`, try `.filter(a, b)`

Comment: ahh.. the more you learn :-)  I tried putting them in the same filter, but unfortunately had the same result. Thanks for the tip though :)